# What's the Difference Between "I would've had to say" and "I would've had to have said"?

Tags: tense

1. If they'd asked me, I would've had to say...
2. If they'd asked me, I would've had to have said...

What's the difference between them?

Comment: The biggest difference is simply that most native speakers would use the first version because it's ***simpler***. Also note that if there's going to be any contraction at all, it's more likely to be [***I'd have had to...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+would+have+had+to%2CI+would%27ve+had+to%2CI%27d+have+had+to%2CI%27d%27ve+had+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20would%20have%20had%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20would%20%27ve%20had%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27d%20have%20had%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%27d%27ve%20had%20to%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: (***Also*** note that many if not most native speakers would pronounce ***had*** here as ***hat***.)

Comment: (***Also also*** note that many native speakers would start off with *If they'd **have** asked me.* Where ***'d*** is ***supposed*** to be contracted from ***would***, but some people - myself included - "unpack" that as ***If they had have asked me...***)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you. I heard this from an American native speaker in his 20's, that's why I asked about it thinking the first one would be simpler just as you said.

Comment: ...or I might just say *I'd **haff** to've said....* (/v/ becomes /f/, just as /d/ becomes /t/ in such contexts).